# Silent Install Mariadb 10.6 on Windows without HeidiSQL

Tags: window, mariadb

By default, mariadb comes with HeidiSQL, so HeidiSQL is automatically installed when installing Mariadb silently on Windows.   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-msi-packages-on-windows/#silent-installation

There is an option to remove the HeidiSQL if I install with UI, but I am not sure how to do with silent-installation. Can anyone help me to unselct HeidiSQL in silent-installation process?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

pass following properties to msiexec /i

- ADDLOCAL=ALL
- REMOVE=HeidiSQL

Example:

```
msiexec /i  mariadb-10.3.9-winx64.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=HeidiSQL /L*V log.LOG /q /passive
```

HeidiSQL is a normal MSI feature, you do not need transforms or such.

If you have an option to remove something with UI, you can do that also with commandline.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward - create a response transform for the GUI installation with HeidiSQL deselected. Then, apply the transform to the existing MSI via the command line.

There are lots of guides on how to create a response transform using different tools; here's some video guide: https://youtu.be/-Thj8rK-Wok